# SQLAlchemy with IBM_DB throwing error driver not found

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, db2

[image: Python packages installed- sqlalchemy, ibm_db, ibm_db_sa]

```
    >python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://useid:password@host:port/db")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\ibm_db.py", line 104, in dbapi
    import ibm_db_dbi as module
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 860

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

even used

```
engine = create_engine("ibm_db_sa+pyodbc400://userid:password@host:port/dbname")
```

But getting error `ibm_db_dbi module as module` or `odbc driver not found`.
I am able to connect if I use only ibm_db, but not through sql_alchemy.
pip installed `sql_alchemy`, `ib_db`, `ibm_db_sa`

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
>>>
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
>>>
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>>
>>> engine = create_engine("ibm_db_sa+pyodbc400://userId:password@host:port/db") #create a database engine
>>>
>>> Base = automap_base() #creating an automap base object
>>> Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True) #point associate the DB engine with the Auto-map base.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 304, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 493, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\automap.py", line 790, in prepare
    autoload_replace=False,
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4438, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2266, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 104, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2373, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2343, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1585, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 304, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\d953351\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 493, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)
```

Comment: That traceback shows a SyntaxError, not a driver error.

Comment: I don't know if this is for privacy reasons or you didn't change it but `engine = create_engine("ibm_db_sa+pyodbc400://userid:password@host:port/dbname")` needs to be filled in with your own details...

Comment: Which ODBC driver are you using access the AS/400 database, is it the clidriver, or is it the pyodbc400 that comes as an option with the IBM product `IBM i access` ?

Comment: I have changed the create_engine args with actual value. For security replaced it with dummy values.

Comment: @mao For driver I have installed 
pip install ibm_db
Do I need to install anything else. If so what it would be. DB is in z/os

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because it mentions pyodbc400 which is specifically for the Db2-for-i series. But in a comment you write that your database is on Db2-for-Z/OS.  You need to be **certain** .

If your database **really** is on Db2-for-Z/OS then at the present time the sqlalchemy [does not support Db2-for-Z/OS](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/issues/86). This may change in future.

However, the `ibm_db` module supports Db2-for-Z/OS, as long as you have the relevant Db2 connect license or your target database is enabled with db2connectactivate, or you connect via a separate Db2-connect-Gateway.

The `ibm_db` module supports Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows,  Db2 on cloud, Db2 for i and Db2 for Z/OS.

sqlalchemy currently supports Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows/cloud . Not sure if it supports Db2 for i.