# Is there a way to create an sqlalchemy engine to IBM as400 using sqlalchemy-jdbcapi 1.2.2

Tags: jdbc, sqlalchemy, db2

I am looking to create a jdbc connection to an ibm db2 as400 using sqlalchamy in python

I think you can use sqlalchemy-jdbcapi 1.2.2.  It says IBM DB2 and IBM DB2 for mainframes is supported

I don't seem to have the format of url string correct.  Does anyone please have an example of the connection url or connection string for the create_engine

I can connect using  jaydebeapi as follows

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
    jclassname='com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver',
    url=host_url,
    driver_args=[user_name,password],
    jars=driver_location
)
```

I can do a conn.cursor() so I am assuming I am connected

When I try to create an sqlalchamy engine as follows

```
engine=create_engine("jdbcapi+jdbc:as400//{}:{}@{};JDBC_DRIVER_PATH='{}'".format(username, password,host_thatworks_elsewhere,driver_location)
```

It keeps on giving me sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string when I think the host is correct.  I've tried // in front of the host a port after it.  I copied the host from my DB tool that i have a connection created with and there is no port number specified there

I am assuming you follow this format for the connection string and add the JDBC_DRIVER_PATH so something like

```
create_engine("jdbcapi+jdbc:as400//username:password@HOST:1521/Database;JDBC_DRIVER_PATH ='x'")
```

other than that I guess try to connect using ibm-db-sa 0.3.7 and pyodbc.  It can not find my odbc driver there and yes I installed it

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db-sa/), the syntax is: `create_engine("db2+ibm_db://user:pass@host[:port]/database")` - but note that this is an adapter which needs to be installed using `pip install ibm-db-sa`, before you can use this specific [external dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/index.html). You also need to set up a `CLASSPATH` environment variable for the DB2 JDBC JAR file (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-jdbcapi/)). I have never tried this for DB2.

Comment: I finally got  the ibm-db-sa sa to work using pyodbc400 instead of ibm_db in that connection string.  Apparently according to this post, that is the driver specically for the i series.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186665/sqlalchemy-with-ibm-db-throwing-error-driver-not-found

Getting it to work with sqlalchemy-jdbcapi 1.2.2. and jdbc still a mystery